# Send Email outlook using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, security, outlook, office365

I am trying to send an email using Excel with this code :

```
Sub SEND_EMAIL()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

' ADRESSE
olMail.To = "selojo7915@rippb.com"
' Subject
olMail.subject = "Line"
' BODY
olMail.body = "this"

olMail.Send
```

When starting this macro i have the following error

[image]

The error is in the last line (olMail.Send)

And every time i am trying to send an email outlook is starting to update and after a moment it's showing error

> Exception de HRESULT : 0x80004004 (E_ABORT)

Comment: Which line of code throws that error? • And what exactly does *"outlook is starting to update"* mean? If outlook is starting online updates everytime then I highly recommend first reboot the computer, if that doesn't help re-install office and make sure all updates run through properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see [a security issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/security/outlook-object-model-security-warnings#send-message-warning) (earlier prompts) because Outlook is configured on the client computer in one of the following ways:

- Uses the default Outlook security settings (that is, no Group Policy set up)
- Uses security settings defined by Group Policy but does not have programmatic access policy applied
- Uses security settings defined by Group Policy which is set to warn when the antivirus software is inactive or out of date

You can create a group policy to prevent security prompts from displaying if any up-to-date antivirus software is installed on the system or just turn these warning off (which is not really recommended).

Read more about that in the [Security Behavior of the Outlook Object Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/How-to/Security/security-behavior-of-the-outlook-object-model) article.

You may consider using the following workarounds:

- Install any antivirus software with latest updates.
- Use a low-level API - Extended MAPI which doesn't trigger security issues. You may also consider Redemption which is a convenient wrapper around Extended MAPI.
- Create a COM add-in which has access to the safe Application instance.
- Use group policy settings to turn such security prompts/issues when dealing with Outlook.
- Also you may consider using third-party components that allow turning off and on dynamically security prompts and issues in Outlook. See [Outlook Security Manager](https://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-security/index.php) for more information.